# Fubini with level set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and
$$
\Gamma := \lbrace (s, t) \in [0, \varepsilon]^2 :0 \leq s \leq t \leq \varepsilon \rbrace
$$
be a triangle. I encountered an integral ($f, g:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sufficiently regular) of the following form:
$$
\int_\Omega \int_{\lbrace z\in \mathbb{R}: g(s, t, z) \geq 0 \rbrace} f(s, t, y)~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d(s, t)}
$$
This really confuses me... . I am not sure how or whether to use Fubini in this case. Is it possible that it simply holds that
$$
\int_\Omega \int_{\lbrace z\in \mathbb{R}: g(s, t, z) \geq 0 \rbrace} f(s, t, y)~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d(s, t)} = \int_{\lbrace(r, p, z) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}: g(r, p, z) \geq 0 \rbrace} f(s, t, y)~\mathrm{d}(s, t, y)\quad ?
$$
Clearly, in both cases, we only integrate over those points such that $g \geq 0$. But does the left hand side integrate over all of them?

I would be glad for help...

Comment: yes, that is true. To see that Fubini is applicable, write the integral over the restricted region as an integral over $\mathbb R$ with a suitable characteristic function in the integral.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see it very clearly now!